# error: destroy link_to with two nested namespaces in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, link-to

i have problem to build the 'link_to' to action "destroy".

I have two nested routes in 'Routes.rb':

```
  namespace :admin do
    namespace :security do
      resources :users
    end
  end
```

'rake routes' prints:

```
  DELETE /admin/security/users/:id(.:format)               admin/security/users#destroy
```

the controller is:

```
  class Admin::Security::UsersController < ApplicationController
    def destroy
      ...
    end
    ...
```

**How to build the link_to with http veb 'delete'?**

I unsuccessful tried:

```
  <%= link_to 'destroy', user, method: :delete %>
  <%= link_to 'destroy', {:controller => "admin/security/users", :action => "destroy", :id =>       user.id}, method: :delete %>
  <%= link_to 'destroy', admin_security_users_path(user), method: :delete %>
  <%= link_to 'destroy', admin_security_user_destroy_path(user), method: :delete %>
```

Comment: have you tried `admin_security_user_path(user), method: :delete? (note singular user)

Comment: yes, i tried but goes to "show" action. not "destroy"

Comment: @polras Can you post the resulting html to some of your attempts?

Comment: @polras Also, is JavaScript enabled in your view?

Comment: @polras - That means that url is correct, but for some reason it sends `get` instead of `delete` method. I am not really sure why it happens though. :(

Comment: @BroiSatse yes. it sends "get" and not "delete". Javascript is enabled. but doesnt work. im trying. I'll post if it works.

Comment: @polras Does the html result for `admin_security_user_path(user), method: :delete` look like this: `<a href='/admin/security/user/#' rel="nofollow" data-method="delete">destroy</a>
` ?

Answer (score 1):

You could try passing only the action and resources and leave the rest up to rails:

**UPDATE**
 You should use namespaces names as a parameter to `url_for`

```
<%= link_to 'destroy', ([:destroy, :admin, :security, user]),  method: :delete %>
```

Comment: This worked for me, minus the unnecessary `:destroy` namespacing: `<%= link_to 'destroy', ([:admin, :security, user]),  method: :delete %>`

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<%= link_to 'destroy', admin_security_user_path(user), method: :delete %>
```

use `admin_security_user_path` and not `admin_security_users_path`

**NOTE:** DELETE is performed on single object of model.
See the **[Official Rails Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing)** Documentation.

Comment: Can you share the complete error stacktrace that you receive in the question?